# Remove deleted page from Google search results

Tags: seo

So I have a website that I recently made changes to, and one of the changes was removing a page from the site. I deleted the page, it doesn't exist anymore.

However, when you search for my site, one of the results is the page that I deleted. People are clicking on the page and getting an error.

How do I remove that page from the search results?

Comment: I think this might be a better fit for http://superuser.com, since it is more about computing in general rather than specifically programming.

Comment: @ZachJohnson, actually, it's more suitable for [webmasters.se.com](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about administrating a website, not programming. Website administration questions may be asked on [webmasters.se], but read [their on-topic page](//webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) first. While some programmers *also* administrate websites, doing so is not actually a programming problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the solution

First get ur site on google webmaster. Then go to site configuration -- > crawler access --> remove url . Click on New removal request and add the page you want to remove and make sure you have added that page to the robots.txt of your site. Google will deindex the page within 24 hrs.

Answer (score 0):

You simply wait for googles robots to find out that it doesn't exist anymore.
A trick that used to work is to upload a sitemap to google where you add the url to the deleted page and set it to top priority and that it changes every day. That way the google robots will prio that page and quicker find out that its not there anymore.

There might be other ways but none that are known to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove specific pages using the webmaster tools I believe.

Yahoo Web tools offer a similar service as I understand it.

This information was correct the last time I tried to do this a little while ago.

Answer (score 0):

You should go to https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/removals and remove the pages which you want.