# Unwanted Crawling of pages

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to detect fake users ( crawlers ) and cURL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12257584/how-to-detect-fake-users-crawlers-and-curl)

some pages of my Website is getting crawled undesirably .

say pages like

abc.com/smarty/templates/1.html

abc.com/smarty/templates/2.html

abc.com/images/1.jpg

abc.com/images

- I want to avoid indexing of these page
- also want to remove these pages from google indexing.

I know to do this using apache setting.But since i am using shared network, i dnt hv access to these.

Please help

Comment: Do you have a robots.txt file and sitemap files in place?

Comment: I really dont know why php-ers put their "core" files into webroot...

Comment: block those page in robots.txt you dont want to  Crawling

Comment: how to make rules in robot.txt , if i want to avoid all pages begining with abc.txt/smarty to not be crawled

Answer (score 3):

You can use a text file robots.txt, that the search motors find and which tells them what pages they can and can't index in your website.

Here is a good article about how to write this file:
[Robots.txt: What it is, Why it’s Used and How to Write it](http://seoroi.com/seo-faq/robotstxt-what-it-is-why-its-used-and-how-to-write-it/)

---

To remove a page from Google was discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2710665/remove-deleted-page-from-google-search-results)

Comment: thanx , also how to remove existing indexed pages?

Comment: And how to remove directory say

i dnt want abc.com/aa/ to be indexed but i want abc/aa/a.php to be indexed

Comment: @PriyaSehpal just use Disallow: aa/* or a* to be more discrete.

Answer (score 0):

in robots.txt add rules like

```
User-agent:    *
Disallow:   /smarty/*
Disallow:   /images/*
```

Answer (score 0):

www.google.com/webmasters/tools/

[image: Pic of webmaster tools!]

You can fetch pages as google
You can remove pages from google's index
you can upload your sitemap and much more.
I think this is exactly what you are looking for.